# Jmeter giving different results on different machine for the same version of the script

Tags: jmeter

I have a performance test script written in Jmeter and there is a test with simple parameterization, where a new param is created, the value is read from .yml file and assigned to the param. Me and my colleague are using the same version of the scripts checked out from the same branch (verified if the commits checked out is the same as well), running same version of Jmeter, both using Mac, with amazon-corretto-8.jdk on our machines. But the test that is supposed to retrieve the param value is failing with 'null' request Body for me whereas it works fine for my teammate. Below is the screenshot of that test. Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcaXr.png)

Comment: ${postbinUrl} is failing? How are you passing it?

Answer (score 0):

Given the value is being read from YAML file my expectation is that you're using some form of Java YAML library like [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/default/) or [eo-yaml](https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml) or whatever. Most probably you have this library locally somewhere in [JMeter classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and your colleague doesn't therefore test fails for him.

So make sure to add all external libraries you're using under the version control or consider using dependency management tool like [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)

In case of any unexpected behavior the answer is always in [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file so going forward consider adding at least essential parts of the log (with errors) to your question as well as screenshots of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener showing request and response details.

Comment: We are not using the libraries but instead opening the GUI using "jmeter -t  <path_to_JMX> -J postbinUrl=<url_to_bin>" command. And below is the snippet of the logs, although there are no errors seen here and a screen shot of the 'View results tree'

Comment: You can use only server DNS hostname or IP address in that field, you cannot use `/` character there

Answer (score 0):

We are not using the libraries but instead opening the GUI using "jmeter -t  -J postbinUrl=" command. And below is the snippet of the logs, although there are no errors seen here and a screen shot of the 'View results tree'

jmeter.log: 
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,702 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,703 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,703 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,703 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,703 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,703 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:31,705 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:32,120 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:32,120 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:32,121 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:32,121 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:32,286 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/.../kraken-qe-load-scripts'
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:33,763 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:33,764 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file /Users/rkrishnan/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.1.1/bin/proxyserver.jks
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,711 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,712 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,712 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,714 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,714 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,773 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,934 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : webHooks
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,934 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 2 threads for group webHooks.
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,934 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,935 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=2 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,948 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: webHooks 1-1
`enter code here`2019-10-03 12:13:47,967 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE1Nj.png)